# How read barcode

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm writing a code, where I want to Scan a barcode and ask for a specific input. Right now I did
it with a "save-button", where I have to ask manually if the input is correct.

But I want to do that automatically when I wrote an input.

My problem:

When I write an input without the "save-button" the program doesn't take the changed input of the textbox. And if I use a while-loop, my program is crashing and it doesn't show the UI.

I want to read it with the variable "self.inp_sn" and ask if there is the right length and only digits. But without success. Maybe there is a way to "delay" the class or make a loop without crashing the system, but sadly I couldn't find any good solution.

The Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QWidget
import sys 

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Seriennummer")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        
        self.set_sn()
        self.click_button()
        self.show()
        
        
    def set_sn(self):
        print(1234)
        self.sn_Textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.sn_Textbox.move(85, 35)
        self.sn_Textbox.resize(130,20)
        self.sn_Textbox.setPlaceholderText('Seriennummer')
        
    def checkstatus(self):
        self.state = 0
        self.inp_sn = self.sn_Textbox.text()
        
        if len(self.inp_sn) ==  7 and self.inp_sn.isdigit():
            print("Your Text: ", self.sn_Textbox.text())
            self.sn_Textbox.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
            self.state = 1
                
        else:
            print(self.inp_sn)
            print("Wrong input")
                    
                
    def click_button(self):
        self.save_sn = QPushButton("Save",self)
        self.save_sn.move(85, 55)
        self.save_sn.clicked.connect(self.checkstatus)

def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    
    
    sys.exit(App.exec())
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Inside your constructor, why are you making this call? self.checkstatus()

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete that. I was testing something.

Answer (score 2):

By default barcodes add an endline(`\n`) so in your case you just have to use the [`editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal:

```py
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Seriennummer")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 100)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.set_sn()
        self.show()

    def set_sn(self):
        print(1234)
        self.sn_Textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.sn_Textbox.move(85, 35)
        self.sn_Textbox.resize(130, 20)
        self.sn_Textbox.setPlaceholderText("Seriennummer")
        self.sn_Textbox.editingFinished.connect(self.checkstatus)

    def checkstatus(self):
        print(self.sn_Textbox.text())

    def click_button(self):
        self.save_sn = QPushButton("Save", self)
        self.save_sn.move(85, 55)
        self.save_sn.clicked.connect(self.checkstatus)
```

Comment: How can I directly check if the input is correct? With this I have to close the window to check the input. I like to check the input while the window is active so I can close the active window only if my output is correct. Bc the barcode is always a random number.

Comment: The input will be checked when you press return. You don't need to close the window for that.

Comment: @PYlearning09 What are you going to verify? A barcode adds an endline to the end, so it is enough to verify the endline. Try and you will check it

Comment: Now i have another problem. If i try to scan my barcode, it always gives me 2 outputs => It goes 2 times through  "checkstatus". I also did a validation. But i can't fix this problem.